# Can iPhone Development Certificates be Reused?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, provisioning

I've developed a number of apps for the iOS devices, and now I'm doing freelance work for other companies as well.  We're at the point of getting all the certificates created, and I'm not clear on the right steps to take.

I've been invited -- and joined -- the client's Development Team in the iOS Provisioning Portal.  There is no Development Certificate for me, however.

Do I need to go through the entire process again to get a new certificate issued, or is there a way to "reuse" the existing certificate I've already got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to have a new development certificate generated by this Development Team you've joined; dev certs are not transferable in that way.

Comment: Unfortunate, but not unexpected.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, bit of a pain to organise things once you do work for various different people!

Answer (score 0):

The "entire process" really isn't much: Use the Keychain to generate a certificate signing request, and then upload the CSR to the portal and wait for an administrator in that development team to approve it. Then download your new certificate.

I suppose it might be possible to re-use the same CSR that you used to generate your old certificate, but there'd be little benefit (you'd still have to upload the CSR and wait for a new certificate) and it might cause a lot of future confusion. Not worth bothering.

Comment: Granted, it's not like an afternoon at the DMV, but it just seems to make sense to me that since the certificate is identifying ME, I should be able to reuse MY certificate across multiple teams.  Apple doesn't seem to agree.  Hence, I have to register for another certificate.

Comment: The certificate doesn't **just** identify you; it identifies you as a member of a particular development team. As far as I know it's invalidated if you ever leave that team.